# PHP скрипт на Linux не выводится на сайт

Tags: php, linux

Я установил apache и php, но только когда я ввожу :

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

на сайт ничего не выводиться...

Это Linux Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Как решить проблему? Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: следуйте мануалу: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-ubuntu-18-04-ru. То что там 18я, а не 20я не принципиально

Answer (score 0):

Сначала нувно установить на серверу php,
для правильного установки нужно узнать установлен ли Apach2 или Nginx  или нет
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-php-on-ubuntu-20-04/